# Having trouble to run report from server from web applicaton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 2005, C# and Crystal Reports 8.5 for development. It's running fine on my development computer, but when I try to to run from the server it is giving me an error.

> **Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer,
>   Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.**

I have these Crystal Reports dlls referenced in my bin folder:

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
- CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
- CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
- CrystalDecisions.Web.dll
- CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Crystal Reports redistributable on the server? Then the webpage would know where to find the referenced assembly.